# magento 2 installation on OCI oracle autonomous linux composer

Tags: oracle-linux

I reviewed all the pages herewith the cloud installation guide but OCI installation is not mentioned properly.

```
     rpm -q al-config
al-config-1.1-1.el7.noarch
```

and

```
     uname -a
Linux oci-magento 5.4.17-2102.202.5.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Sat May 22 16:17:06 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 php -v
PHP 7.4.20 (cli) (built: Jun  3 2021 21:06:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

     httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 ()
Server built:   Nov 10 2020 12:35:43

yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
repo id                         repo name                                 status
ol7_UEKR6/x86_64                Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Rele    323
ol7_addons/x86_64               Oracle Linux 7Server Add ons (x86_64)        499
ol7_developer_php74/x86_64      Oracle Linux 7Server PHP 7.4 Packages for    575
ol7_ksplice                     Ksplice for Oracle Linux 7Server (x86_64) 14,712
ol7_latest/x86_64               Oracle Linux 7Server Latest (x86_64)      22,772
ol7_oci_included/x86_64         Oracle Software for OCI users on Oracle L  1,118
ol7_optional_latest/x86_64      Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86 16,318
ol7_software_collections/x86_64 Software Collection Library release 3.0 p 16,586
ol7_x86_64_userspace_ksplice    Ksplice aware userspace packages for Orac    540
repolist: 73,443
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/scl-user/ol-scl-relnotes.html#section_zlg_m3g_dq

```
     php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
zlib
```

but I can not install :

```
 yum -y install php74u-pdo php74u-mysqlnd php74u-opcache php74u-xml php74u-gd php74u-devel php74u-mysql php74u-intl php74u-mbstring php74u-bcmath php74u-json php74u-iconv php74u-soap
```

thanks
sayantan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 yum install php-* --skip-broken
```

this thing mostly worked well for me and

```
       php -m
 [PHP Modules]
    bcmath
    bz2
    calendar
    Core
    ctype
    curl
    date
    dba
    dom
    enchant
    exif
    fileinfo
    filter
    ftp
    gd
    gettext
    gmp
    hash
    iconv
    imap
    intl
    json
    ldap
    libxml
    mbstring
    mysqli
    mysqlnd
    odbc
    openssl
    pcntl
    pcre
    PDO
    pdo_mysql
    PDO_ODBC
    pdo_pgsql
    pdo_sqlite
    pgsql
    Phar
    posix
    pspell
    readline
    Reflection
    session
    shmop
    SimpleXML
    snmp
    soap
    sockets
    SPL
    sqlite3
    standard
    sysvmsg
    sysvsem
    sysvshm
    tidy
    tokenizer
    xml
    xmlreader
    xmlrpc
    xmlwriter
    xsl
    Zend OPcache
    zip
    zlib
    
    [Zend Modules]
    Zend OPcache
```

thx
sayantan